# Homegrown authentication filter does not show the welcome page

Tags: security, jsf, authentication, servlet-filters

So I've come accross quite a numbre of questions similar to mine, and I was starting to get it until I realised I don't, in short, here's the story :

In an authentification bean, success of authentification should result in accessing some web resources, failure should "filter" access and redirect to current login page.
Now, in that authentification bean, I added this line in case of success :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(authentificationBean1.AUTH_STATE, "true") ;
```

**AUTH_STATE** is defined in the bean as :

```
public static final String AUTH_STATE = "";
```

In case of failure, I do the following :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(authentificationBean1.AUTH_STATE, null) ;
```

Now in the filter (one that is applied to every file except of authentification page), my doFilter method looks like this :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute(authentificationBean1.AUTH_STATE) == null) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("authentification.xhtml");

        } 

        if(((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute(authentificationBean1.AUTH_STATE) != null) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("accueil.xhtml");
        }

    }
```

My idea was that if authentification went well, the **authentificationBean1.AUTH_STATE** session attribut will be set to something not null, thus in the filter test I'll be able to redirect to a welcom page (accueil.xhtml) ; if that attribut is null, we'll stay in the authentification page.

Tasting the whole thing : the filter seems to work but too much, by that I mean even when authentification test must succeed it doesn't allow me to pass to the welcome page. It was actually working fine without the filter, it looks like I missed something about using filters with JSF or filters as it.

P.S : didn't apply chain.doFilter because I do not have another filter to call, but suspecting something there.

Thanks for your indications.

EDIT :

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>beans.RestrictionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/accueil.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you post your web.xml?

Comment: Sure thing (sorry for being late), I'll edit my initial post.

Comment: I've made few System.out here in there, what I can notice now is that when the **AUTH_STATE** is null, it's not taken into account, otherwise I got the filter to work in the othercase (where **AUTH_STATE** is not null).

Comment: Ok, just noticed - I think you only need the first condition (`.getAttribute(authentificationBean1.AUTH_STATE) == null`). The second one might cause an endless loop. As I understand, the second one is for a case of an authenticated user, so you don't have to redirect him/her anywhere.

Comment: Actuall, it is the != null condition that's functionnal for me at the moment. But I can see that I don't have to redirect him in case of failure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter is running in an infinite loop, redirecting to itself everytime. It is never continuing the request to the servlet. It seems that you're misunderstood how HTTP works. With `response.sendRedirect()` you're basically firing a brand new HTTP request. This brand new HTTP request will invoke the filter again. So, when your filter matches the condition in order to redirect to `accueil.xhtml`, it will keep redirecting to that page in an infinite loop and never continue to the servlet in order to process the request.

Further you also misunderstood the meaning of `chain.doFilter()`. It does not explicitly advance to the next filter. It just **continues** the request as if there was no filter. Whether there's another filter next in the chain or not is completely irrelevant. If there's no filter, then it will just end up in the target servlet (which is the `FacesServlet` in your case, who's responsible for processing the JSF page).

Basically, the flow should be as follows:

- If the user is not logged in, then:

  - If the currently requested page is not `authentification.xhtml`, then redirect to it.
  - Or if the currently requested page is already `authentification.xhtml`, then continue request.
- Or if the user is logged in, then continue the request regardless of the requested page.

In other words, this should do it:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/authentification.xhtml";

    boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute(authentificationBean1.AUTH_STATE) != null;
    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(loginURL);
    boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

    if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
    }
}
```

Note that I also added a check on JSF resources (the CSS/JS/image files included via `<h:outputStylesheet|outputScript|graphicImage>`), otherwise they would also be blocked when the login page is presented. Also note that this filter can be mapped on `/*` and not on only a single page.

Comment: endless loop, that one I didn't imagine... So a filter is fired up everytime I try to access a "filtred" ressource, right ?

Comment: A filter is invoked on every HTTP request matching the URL pattern. A redirect instructs the client to create a new HTTP request. Basically, your filter kept instructing the client to create a new HTTP request.

Comment: Now for example I've mapped my filter to accueil.xhtml, that means everytime that page is called the filter will intervene to "doFiltre" something, no ? Sorry for insisting, read few articles but they seem just to present code without the underground mechanisms, and hopefully you'll be able to redirect me to some fine  tutorial.

Comment: That's correct. A filter which is mapped on `<url-pattern>` is invoked when the HTTP request matches the URL pattern. Exactly the same is true for a servlet, by the way, however they are invoked *after* filters. So if a filter aborts the request by instructing the client to create a new request (a redirect), it never comes to the servlet. You should have used `chain.doFilter()` to continue the current request when no redirect is needed for the current request. This is exactly what my answer shows.

Comment: I see, thanks, thank Chichiray for me as I think he's helping you with answering so many questions.